# LinkedIn API "Time-Bound Follower Statistics" Data Discrepancy

Tags: linkedin-api, unix-timestamp

I am currently working on a project that involves retrieving "Time-Bound Follower Statistics" data from the LinkedIn API. However, I have noticed a significant discrepancy between the data returned by the LinkedIn API and the data displayed on the LinkedIn website.

On the LinkedIn website(Company analysis page), the follower statistics appear to be accurate and up-to-date. However, when I make API requests to retrieve the same data, I'm getting results that do not match what's displayed on the LinkedIn website. This inconsistency is causing challenges in my project, and I'm struggling to understand why this is happening.

---

Here are some additional details:

- I'm using the LinkedIn API with the following endpoint:
  [https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A(URN_NUMBER_HERE)&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1664582400000,end:1696665665000),timeGranularityType:MONTH)"](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A(URN_NUMBER_HERE)&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1664582400000,end:1696665665000),timeGranularityType:MONTH)%22)).
- I have double-checked my API requests and parameters to ensure they are correct.
- I have also reviewed the LinkedIn API documentation, but I couldn't find any information about potential data discrepancies in the "Time-Bound Follower Statistics."

To illustrate this issue, I have attached an image below that provides a side-by-side comparison of the data:[image: Data Discrepancy side-by-side comparison LI]

I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to help me address this problem.